# Dojo Boilerplate Build Warnings

Tags: dojo, dojo-build

Today I cloned the [Dojo Boilerplate](http://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate/) and I'm running `build.sh` for the first time.

Messages like `"warn(216) dojo/has plugin resource could not be resolved during build-time"` are showing up in the console, and I wonder how much these *warnings* matter.  Should I try to resolve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There always will be a lot of this kinds of warnings in build report. I seldom find that this will cause issues in your final building.

Don't worry about warning, just go head. Unless you see some errors in the report, you need to fix the errors.

Here is standard response from dojo https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15903

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep to filer out messages starting for ex. from warn or info

> src/util/buildscripts/build.sh --profile devel.profile.js | grep -vE "^warn|^info"